# .rdl file sorting items

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdl

I am trying to sort the fields (generic_quarter_short_name) from rdl file. the generic_quarter_short_name are q1, q2, q3, q4

```
 <SortExpression>
 <Value>=Fields!generic_quarter_short_name.Value</Value>
 </SortExpression>
```

but, I want to sort this names q4, q1, q2, q3. q4 should be first and then q1, q2, q3

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=VAL(RIGHT(Fields!generic_quarter_short_name.Value, 1)) MOD 4
```

Briefly: Take the right 1 character, convert it to a number then apply MOD.
The MOD function will take 1,2,3,4 and return 1,2,3,0

Comment: If this answer helped, please mark it as accepted. I noticed that you have asked several questions but never marked any as accepted.